# How to Use CSS Mask in IE and Mozilla

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, mozilla, mask

I came across this CSS property for [IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff972267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask)
I intend to mask an HTML element but I can't seem to work it. Please I need your help, this is my code

```
.download {
mask: url(image/download.svg#Capa_1);
-webkit-mask: url("image/download.svg") top left / cover;}
```

and this is my SVG file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.4, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  --><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
  <path d="M256,288l128-128h-96V32h-64v128h-96L256,288z M372.363,235.636l-35.87,35.871L466.533,320L256,398.509L45.467,320
        l130.04-48.493l-35.871-35.871L0,288v128l256,96l256-96V288L372.363,235.636z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: `mask` is not supported by IE..at all. http://caniuse.com/css-masks  A Jsfiddle would be useful. Partial support in Firefox refers to only support for **inline** SVG mask elements i.e. mask: url(#foo).

Comment: How can i use the Jsfiddle to achieve this effect please @Paulie_D

Comment: My point was that I don't think it's possible at the moment. Check the links/articles on the CanIUse page.

Comment: You need to use SVG Masking in Firefox (more details at http://robert.ocallahan.org/2008/06/applying-svg-effects-to-html-content_04.html). As @Paulie_D said there's no IE solution currently though.

Comment: IE supports mask *inside* of svg, so if it's an option to convert the elements you want to mask to svg then it should be possible.

Comment: @ErikDahlström thanks for your comment, but can you elaborate more on this or send me a detailed web-link on how this can be achieved, I am grateful

Comment: http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking is one such resource, but if you can use just svg it can be done much simpler than this article suggests. I'd recommend trying out http://codepen.io/madebyjam/pen/zmBen/ (which generates a clip-path, but that can easily be replaced by a mask).

Answer (score 1):

Use SVG for the content and the mask. For example:

```html
<svg>
<defs>
  <mask id="mask1" x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="1000" >
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="1000"
        style="stroke:none; fill: #999999"/>
  </mask>
</defs>


<rect x="1" y="1" width="100" height="100"
    style="stroke: none; fill: #000000; mask: url(#mask1)"/>
</svg>
```

**References**

- [SVG Masks](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/mask.html)